# How to find a specific file and move it to a specific directory?

Tags: linux, find, mv

How to find a specific file, and move it to the specific directory `/var/tmp`?

For example I want to find the file `0914_Jul-2014.gz`.

Remark, the file `0914_Jul-2014.gz`, is under ~300 subdirectories:

```
      /usr/../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../0914_Jul-2014.gz
```

An example: when I do a

```
find /usr -name '0914_Jul-2014.gz' -exec mv {} /var/tmp
```

The result is

`mv: cannot stat: File name too long`

error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find /usr -name '0914_Jul-2014.gz' -exec mv {} /var/tmp \;
```

Or for extremely nested directory hierarchies

```
find /usr -name '0914_Jul-2014.gz' -execdir mv {} /var/tmp \;
```

Although as the documentation states you must ensure that  your  `$PATH` environment  variable  does not reference the current directory (namely `.`) if you use `-execdir`

Comment: I get  File name too long ( because the .gz file is under 300 sub dir )

Comment: see my update in the question

Comment: @maihabunash, change `-exec` to `-execdir` and give it a shot. Before doing that make sure your `PATH` variable does not reference current directory (ie it does not contain `.`)

Comment: yes its work , create answer and I will vote for you

Comment: @maihabunash, added to jordanm's answer and upvoted ;-).

Comment: you got it thx for the support

Comment: what's the meaning of `\;` at the end?

Comment: for me I use this 
find -user john -group john -exec cp -rp {} /root/files \;
the \; at the end is important we need to include

Answer (score 3):

Use `locate` to find the file:

```
locate <file_name>
```

Then use `mv` to move the file

```
mv <location/file_name> <new_location/file_name>
```

Comment: The path to the file is already known. There is no way `locate` could be in any way useful.